# CSS styling not working in HTML Imports with Firefox

Tags: css, html

Even though Mozilla has regrettably announced that they had no intention of shipping HTML Imports in the near future, it [seems possible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) to enable them in Firefox via the dom.webcomponent.enabled preference in about:config.

I am currently experimenting with this feature as I believe that imports would be a great addition to web development. Now for some reason, I can't seem to make it work properly with the following setup:

- One main document called **main.html**
- One secondary document that is imported into the first one, called **import.html**
- Finally, a CSS file called **import.css** that is linked to **import.html**

**main.html**  contains the following code:

```
 <head>
  <link rel="import" href="import.html">
  </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
        var content = link.import;
        var grab = content.querySelector('.importme'); 
        document.body.appendChild(grab.cloneNode(true));
      </script>
    </body>
```

While **import.html** contains:

```
<link href="import.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="importme">
  <p>This is the import</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS file simply reads:

```
p{ color: blue; }
```

When I load **main.html**, the paragraph displays successfully, however none of the CSS styling is applied (in this case, the text color is still black).

It seems to work just fine in Chrome, however (which is now supposed to handle imports by default - note that this only works in Chrome if the page is uploaded to and loaded from a server first).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Reading the page online doesn't do it for Firefox either (still getting a black paragraph). I'd really need to make this work offline as having to constantly upload my pages online to view them with Chrome isn't really a practical option.

Comment: are you checking if `link.import` is returning anything?

Comment: you mean in the console? it returns HTMLDocument

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Clear the browser cache. See if that works(It should work).
2. Use ~/ followed by path. See, if that works.
3. Lastly, use absolute URLs if nothing works.

Comment: clearing the cache didn't help unfortunately. should the path be <link href="~/import.css" rel="stylesheet"> or include the path leading to the directory as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the where the script is executed.  The script in main.html is executed within the domain of main.html, not import.html.  The link to import.css does not exist in main.html.  I think if you put the css link in main.html instead of import.html it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML import is not supported by firefox by default. For more details, See this http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports